# How to call aspx page from other project to my mvc project in actionresult

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have MVC project in which I am trying to call other web application aspx page on action link click. How do I pass that link in ActionResult or return view().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Controller's `Redirect()` method.

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
    // ...
    return Redirect("http://www.example.com");
}
```